# How can I make a visitor pattern configurable in runtime?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, visitor-pattern, abstract-factory, prototype-pattern

Well, as you know, the design pattern Visitor has a "problem" similar to Abstract Factory problem: the more visitable classes I made, the more specific "visit" methods must create.

In the case of an abstract factory I made a solution using prototype of a product to "configure" the factory:

*factory.h*

```
class ExtensibleFactory
{
public:
    ~ExtensibleFactory();

    void insertProductType(const string &nome, IProductPrototype *product);
    void removeProductType(const string &nome);
    IProductPrototype *createProduct(const string &nome);

private:
    map<string, IProductPrototype *> m_productsHash;
};
```

*factory.cpp*

```
#include "extensiblefactory.h"

#include "iproductprototype.h"

ExtensibleFactory::~ExtensibleFactory()
{
    for(map<string, IProductPrototype *>::iterator iter = this->m_productsHash.begin(); iter != this->m_productsHash.end(); ++iter)
    {
        delete iter->second;
    }

    this->m_productsHash.clear();
}

void ExtensibleFactory::insertProductType(const string &nome, IProductPrototype *product)
{
    this->m_productsHash.insert(make_pair(nome, product));
}

void ExtensibleFactory::removeProductType(const string &nome)
{
    delete this->m_productsHash[nome];
    this->m_productsHash.erase(nome);
}

IProductPrototype *ExtensibleFactory::createProduct(const string &nome)
{
    if ( this->m_productsHash.find(nome) == this->m_productsHash.end() )
    {
      return 0;
    }

    return this->m_productsHash[nome]->clone();
}
```

*main.cpp*

```
SanduichePrototype *sanduiche = new SanduichePrototype;
CarroPrototype *carro = new CarroPrototype;

ExtensibleFactory *fabrica = new ExtensibleFactory;

fabrica->insertProductType("sanduba", sanduiche);
fabrica->insertProductType("automovel", carro);

IProductPrototype *carro1 = fabrica->createProduct("automovel");
IProductPrototype *carro2 = fabrica->createProduct("automovel");

IProductPrototype *sanduiche1 = fabrica->createProduct("sanduba");
IProductPrototype *sanduiche2 = fabrica->createProduct("sanduba");
```

Now, consider this visitor and its elements:

*ivisitor.h*

```
class ElementA;
class ElementB;

class IVisitor
{
public:
    virtual void visit(ElementA *elementA) = 0;
    virtual void visit(ElementB *elementB) = 0;
};
```

*ielement.h*

```
class IVisitor;

class IElement
{
public:
    virtual void accept(IVisitor *visitor) = 0;
};
```

*elementa.h*

```
class ElementA : public IElement
{
public:
    virtual void accept(IVisitor *visitor);
};
```

*elementb.h*

```
class ElementB : public IElement
{
public:
    virtual void accept(IVisitor *visitor);
};
```

If I want to add more elements I will have to add more methods do IVisitor interface.

I wish to know if it's possible to "configure" a visitor in runtime, in other words, I want to know if there are any solution to emulate the act of adding more methods to the IVisitor interface by configuring it just like I did to Factory pattern and, if so, which will be the possible solutions.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As well, post all code here, do not link to external sites.

Comment: Well, I posted a link to external due to huge size of code...

Comment: If the code is too large to post, post en equivalent but slimmed down version of the problem.

Comment: I don't see anything about visitor pattern in the posted code. Not voting to close as unclear because it could be just that I'm slow on the uptake.

Comment: Not related to your question, but if C++11 is available to you consider using std::unique_ptr.

Comment: Thanks, I will consider it. :)

Comment: Andrei Alexandrescu provided a pretty thorough discussion of various implementation strategies for visitor pattern in his "Modern C++ Design" book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action (visitor) object you want to pass around to objects will have to have hardwired at least knowledge of some common base class whose functionality it can use, and then as I see it there's not much point in dynamically *registering* visitable classes, because you need a dynamic dispatch anyway, e.g. `dynamic_cast`, and with that the need to list all supported classes in the common visitor interface, disappears.

Consider first a slight refactoring of your visitor pattern code – except for generality and naming and access it's the same as your code:

```
// Static visitor pattern.

template< class Visitable >
class Visitor_
{
template< class > friend class Visitable_impl_;
private:
    virtual void visit( Visitable& ) {}
};

class A;
class B;

class I_visitor
    : public Visitor_<A>
    , public Visitor_<B>
{};

class I_visitable
{
public:
    virtual void accept( I_visitor& ) = 0;
};

template< class Visitable >
class Visitable_impl_
    : public I_visitable
{
public:
    void accept( I_visitor& v )
        override
    {
        static_cast<Visitor_<Visitable>&>( v )          // Cast for access.
            .visit( static_cast<Visitable&>( *this ) ); // Cast for overload res.
    }
};

class A: public Visitable_impl_<A> {};
class B: public Visitable_impl_<B> {};

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

auto main()
    -> int
{
    class Action
        : public I_visitor
    {
    private:
        void visit( A& ) override { cout << "Visited an A." << endl; }
    };

    I_visitable&&       a   = A();
    I_visitable&&       b   = B();
    Action              x;

    a.accept( x );  b.accept( x );
}
```

Now we just replace the first `static_cast` with a `dynamic_cast`, and voilà:

```
// Dynamic visitor pattern.

template< class Visitable >
class Visitor_
{
template< class > friend class Visitable_impl_;
private:
    virtual void visit( Visitable& ) {}
};

struct I_visitor { virtual ~I_visitor(){} };    // Note: no mention of A or B.

class I_visitable
{
public:
    virtual void accept( I_visitor& ) = 0;
};

template< class Visitable >
class Visitable_impl_
    : public I_visitable
{
public:
    void accept( I_visitor& v )
        override
    {
        if( auto p_visitor = dynamic_cast<Visitor_<Visitable>*>( &v ) )
        {
            p_visitor->visit( static_cast<Visitable&>( *this ) );   // Cast for overload res.
        }
    }
};

class A: public Visitable_impl_<A> {};
class B: public Visitable_impl_<B> {};

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

auto main()
    -> int
{
    class Action
        : public I_visitor
        , public Visitor_<A>
    {
    private:
        void visit( A& ) override { cout << "Visited an A." << endl; }
    };

    I_visitable&&       a   = A();
    I_visitable&&       b   = B();
    Action              x;

    a.accept( x );  b.accept( x );
}
```

Comment: So you can not add class registers at runtime apparently. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @GugaLoks: If you consider the `Action` in the code above, the pertinent fact about it, wrt. using it, is that it's an `I_visitor`. So you can easily create a collection of `I_visitor` pointers, say, where these can be added at run time, perhaps each providing a visitor for a different class, and have a function that iterates trough the collection and passes them to a given `accept`. But, what would be the point?

Comment: A visitor that visits more than one class is hard to make with this technique, let's say I want an action that visit both A and B.

Comment: @GugaLoks: There's no problem. In class `Action` add public inheritance of `Visitor_<B>`, and provide the `B` override. What did you think was the problem?

Comment: Nothing, as you said before "I'm slow on the uptake"... Thank you very much for the the answer, explanations and especially for the patience. :)

Comment: further doubt: why did you use && in I_Visitable&& a = A(); ?

Comment: @GugaLoks: In order to bind the `A()` instance to a reference to non-`const`. I wanted the reference in order to demonstrate that all the compiler knows about the instance at the point where `accept` is called, is that it's an `I_Visitable`. An alternative way to show that could be to declare the `A` and `B` instances and call a function with `I_Visitable&` formal arguments, where then the calls to `accept` would be placed.